# Orbit of a set of permutations

Tags: sage

In GAP, we can find the orbit of a set of permutations easily enough:

```
grp := Group([ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ]);;
els := Elements(grp);;
O := Orbit(grp, els{[1,2,3,4]}, OnSets);

[ [ (), (2,3,5,4), (2,4,5,3), (2,5)(3,4) ], [ (), (1,3)(4,5), (1,4,3,5), (1,5,3,4) ],
  [ (), (1,2,5,4), (1,4,5,2), (1,5)(2,4) ], [ (), (1,2)(3,5), (1,3,2,5), (1,5,2,3) ],
  [ (), (1,2,4,3), (1,3,4,2), (1,4)(2,3) ] ]
```

I'd like to do this in Sage (preferably without invoking the GAP interface). In the documentation, I found the following: http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/perm_gps/permgroup.html#sage.groups.perm_gps.permgroup.PermutationGroup_generic.orbit

They provide the following "OnSets" example:

```
sage: S3 = groups.permutation.Symmetric(3)
sage: S3.orbit((1,2), action = "OnSets")
({1, 2}, {2, 3}, {1, 3})
```

So I tried the following:

```
grp = PermutationGroup([ '(1,2,3,4,5)', '(1,2,4,3)' ])
els = list(grp)
grp.orbit(els[:4], action = "OnSets")

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Does anyone have any idea how to compute this properly? Currently, I'm getting around this using gap.eval:

```
gap.eval("grp := Group([ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ])")
gap.eval("els := Elements(grp)")
gap.eval("test_orbit := Orbit(grp, els{[1,2,3,4]}, OnSets)")
O = gap.new("test_orbit")
```

Now any calculation I do using 'O' is incredibly slow, so I'd like to try do everything in Sage, or somehow convert 'O' into a proper Sage object that's quick to work with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the example the set in question is a subgroup; then a better way is to build an action on cosets.

Also, we don't recomment using GAP pexpect interface, use libgap instead.
Then your example may be written as follows (I only used abother way to create the subset of permutations to act on):

```
sage: grp = libgap(PermutationGroup([ '(1,2,3,4,5)', '(1,2,4,3)' ])); grp
Group([ (1,2,3,4,5), (1,2,4,3) ])
sage: s=grp.Stabilizer(1)
sage: grp.Orbit(s.Elements(),libgap.OnSets)
[ [ (), (2,3,5,4), (2,4,5,3), (2,5)(3,4) ], [ (), (1,3)(4,5), (1,4,3,5), (1,5,3,4) ], [ (), (1,2,5,4), (1,4,5,2), (1,5)(2,4) ], [ (), (1,2)(3,5), (1,3,2,5), (1,5,2,3) ], [ (), (1,2,4,3), (1,3,4,2), (1,4)(2,3) ] ]
```

Comment: I really like how the `libgap.OnSets` just fits right in there as an argument, nice syntax.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to somehow Sage not being ready to deal with this input recursively.  Here is the relevant code (you can find this by doing `grp.orbit??`):

```
    def input_for_gap(x, depth, container):
        if depth == len(container):
            try:
                return self._domain_to_gap[x]
            except KeyError:
                raise ValueError('{0} is not part of the domain'.format(x))
        x = [input_for_gap(xx, depth+1, container) for xx in x]
        if container[depth] is Set:
            x.sort()
        return x
```

But `grp._domain_to_gap` yields the dictionary `{1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 3, 4: 4, 5: 5}`, which clearly isn't going to do much interesting with elements like `()` or even others (this is the second time through this recursion that it will happen).

The problem is that there needs to be another layer of recursion here, but for some reason that was not considered.   I have opened [Ticket 29151](https://trac.sagemath.org/ticket/29151) for this.

Comment: Thanks for opening the ticket. It'd be great to get that orbit function to work properly in Sage. I've posted an answer of how you can implement GAP's `Orbit` command directly in Sage via conjugation.

Comment: I'll put a link to that on the ticket as well, though with LibGAP hopefully it should be a bit faster if done "properly".  Thanks!

Comment: please see my answer below - if you use libgap you can get closer to what you fo in GAP (and it will be faster too)

Answer (score 1):

While I could not get the Sage 'orbit' command to work properly, I am able to compute the desired orbit by implementing the function directly. In GAP, the function: `Orbit(grp, els{[1,2,3,4]}, OnSets)` has x in `grp`act on `els{[1,2,3,4]}` via conjugation of each of the y in `els`; i.e. xyx^{-1}. I've implemented this in Sage using the following:

```
grp = PermutationGroup([ '(1,2,3,4,5)', '(1,2,4,3)' ])
indices = [1,2,3,4]
els = list(grp)
perm = [els[i-1] for i in indices] #Convert 'indices' into permutations from 'els'

O = []
for x in els:
    temp_O = []
    for y in perm:
        temp_O.append(x*y*x.inverse()) #Conjugation step

    if (temp_O in O) == False:
        O.append(temp_O)
```

Then `O = [[(), (1,5,4,3,2), (1,4,2,5,3), (1,3,5,2,4)], [(), (1,2,3,4,5), (1,3,5,2,4), (1,4,2,5,3)], [(), (1,4,2,5,3), (1,2,3,4,5), (1,5,4,3,2)], [(), (1,3,5,2,4), (1,5,4,3,2), (1,2,3,4,5)]]`.

Note that while this is a different set than `O` above (in GAP), GAP and Sage index the permutations of a group differently (different orders); i.e. the indices `[1,2,3,4]` correspond to different permutations in each program. Both these functions do indeed return the same values. The script written above (in Sage) computes at a comparable speed to GAP's `Orbit` function.